# Form modified via jQuery - Not able to retrieve multiple field values

Tags: jquery, forms, dom, live, each

I have some problems when trying to get multiple fields from a jQuery form.

I use a form to create projects. The number of tasks is not predefined, so new form fields to add new tasks can be created dynamically via jQuery:

***HTML FORM***

```
<form action="#" id="createProjectForm" method="post">
<fieldset id="Project">
<label for="title">Title:</label>
<label for="title">Coordinator:</label>
<input type="text" id="coordinator" name="coordinator" placeholder="COORDINATOR" />         
<div id="tasks">
<hr/>
<label for="taskTitle">Task:</label>
<input type="text" id="taskTitle" name="taskTitle" placeholder="TASK TITLE" />
</div>
<label for="createTask"></label>            
<input type="button" id="createTask" value="ADD NEW TASK" />
<label for="submitTask"></label>            
<input type="submit" id="submitTask" value="SAVE AND CREATE PROJECT" />
</form>
```

***JQUERY***

```
$("#createTask").live("click",function() {                  
$('#tasks').clone().insertAfter("#tasks");
});
```

When I clone the div "tasks", I can correctly see two "taskTitle" input fields for new tasks, but when trying to get the values (with "each"):

***JQUERY***

```
$("#createProjectForm").live("submit",function() {
var taskTitles = "";
$("#taskTitle").each(function(){
taskTitles += $.trim($(this).val()) + ",";
console.log("Task: "+taskTitles);
});
```

I just get the value of the first field, not the second one, like if it wasn't properly stored in the DOM...

Any suggestion?
Thanks!

Comment: ID's should be unique.. you are using an `ID` selector so you will always only get the first element it finds in the dom with that `ID`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you clone an item with an id the cloned item gains that same id. Jquery's id selector only selects the first match. (See here http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)